# Storing structs as bytes

Tags: swift, memory-management

I need to store a struct as a byte array in swift

```swift
func store(_ structPtr: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int)  {
  let structBytes = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(
    start: structPtr,
    count: size
  )

  structBytes.enumerated().forEach { (idx, byte) in
    byteArray[indexIntoArrayOfTheStruct + idx] = byte
  }
}

struct Test {
  var val: Int
}
let test = Test(val: 8)

store(&test, MemoryLayout<Test>.size)
```

This works as `Int` is a value type, but when storing a String, this will not work because the string will be deallocated.

```swift
strurct Test {
  var val: String
}
```

How can I keep the struct from being deallocated, like there is Unmanaged for a class?

Comment: Are you trying to serialize struct to disk by doing this?

Comment: @Alexander no, I’m storing them into an array to be accessed later. I’m doing it this way rather than an array of a protocol because this is more performant, which is necessary in my case

Comment: If the existential container boxing if a perf issue for you, you can make an enum to match your protocol, with one case (with associated value) for each conforming type. It'll be much easier, and importantly, safer.

Comment: @Alexander That would be the best option. The reason I didn't go for that is that it becomes harder to use the library I'm building. Enum is the sensible option tough. If I don'f find another way, then I'll use the enum

Comment: This way lies madness, honestly, I'd strongly recommend against it. You'll essentially need to use reflection (for which an official API doesn't really exist yet) to identify all their fields, infer their memory management strategy, and add releases and retains as necessary. It'll be ridiculously hard, and I guarantee you it'll have memory-unsafe bugs.

Comment: @Alexander I know of way I might achieve this still, which should fit my particular use case. Basically I have different structs that store different types of implementors. So if I allocate those structs and store pointers to them in an array, I can use regular arrays to store my structs. Since those wrapper structs are only deallocated at the end of a program, I shouldn't have many memory safety issues

Comment: How would those wrapper struct help? They’re just one extra layer of wrapping. A one-property struct in Swift has equivalent memory layout to the one stored property, so really a pointer to one of your wrapper is no different to a pointer of your original structs

Comment: @Alexander the difference is that those wrappers are not changed frequently and only deallocated at the end of the program. Plus I already have those structs in my case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251524/discussion-between-alexander-and-jomy).